# Array Merge sort Sorting Count and Sorting time Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have created a program where numbers are generated randomly for a list/ array. In this list, I need to calculate how long it will take to sort the list and also the number of swaps it will take to sort.

The below is my code. The code solves the list without any issue but the time and swap counter aren't working properly it just gives me 0,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,2,4 like results.

Am I doing something wrong when adding to count and also at the start.time and end.time

```
import random
import time
#X--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Random Number Generator
def random_generator():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, 1000)
    return randomNumber
#X--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def arraygenerator():
    arr = []
    for draw in range(8):
        randomNumber = random_generator()
        arr.append(randomNumber)
    print ("Unsorted Array is : ", arr)
    return arr
#X--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Insertion Sort
def mergeSort(A):
    

    b = 0
    start = time.time() # Start Timmer
    if len(A) > 1:
 
         # Finding the mid of the array
            mid = len(A)//2
 
        # Dividing the array elements
            L = A[:mid]
 
        # into 2 halves
            R = A[mid:]
 
        # Sorting the first half
            mergeSort(L)
 
        # Sorting the second half
            mergeSort(R)
 
            i = j = k = 0
            
 
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
            while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
                if L[i] < R[j]:
                    A[k] = L[i]
                    i += 1
                    
                else:
                    A[k] = R[j]
                    j += 1
                k += 1
                b = b+1
 
        # Checking if any element was left
            while i < len(L):
                A[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1
                
 
            while j < len(R):
                A[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1
 
    end = time.time() # End Timmer
    printf(end, start, b)
    
    
      

def printf(end, start, b):
    
    print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
    print ("Total Number of Swaps : ", b)
    

A = arraygenerator()

mergeSort(A)
print ("Sorted array", A)
```

```
Unsorted Array is :  [684, 508, 361, 743, 745, 353, 521, 55]
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.031590938568115234
Total Number of Swaps :  1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.02653813362121582
Total Number of Swaps :  1
Runtime of the program is 0.08834385871887207
Total Number of Swaps :  3
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.023435115814208984
Total Number of Swaps :  1
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.0
Total Number of Swaps :  0
Runtime of the program is 0.024811744689941406
Total Number of Swaps :  1
Runtime of the program is 0.07755494117736816
Total Number of Swaps :  3
Runtime of the program is 0.1909334659576416
Total Number of Swaps :  7
Sorted array [55, 353, 361, 508, 521, 684, 743, 745]
```

Comment: You're calling `mergeSort` recursively – each recursive invocation will count their own time and number of swaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment: since you call `mergeSort` recursively, you'll need to wrap that with another function to measure the start and end times.

Then, to keep proper track of the number of swaps, since `mergeSort` mutates the array in-place, you can use `return` to return the number of swaps made by that (possibly inner, recursive) `mergeSort` invocation:

```
import random
import time


def _merge_sort(A):
    swaps = 0
    if len(A) > 1:

        # Finding the mid of the array
        mid = len(A) // 2

        # Dividing the array elements
        L = A[:mid]

        # into 2 halves
        R = A[mid:]

        # Sorting the first half
        swaps += _merge_sort(L)

        # Sorting the second half
        swaps += _merge_sort(R)

        i = j = k = 0

        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                A[k] = L[i]
                i += 1

            else:
                A[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
            swaps += 1

        # Checking if any element was left
        while i < len(L):
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

    return swaps


def mergeSort(A):
    start = time.time()  # Start Timmer
    swaps = _merge_sort(A)
    end = time.time()  # End Timmer
    print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
    print("Total Number of Swaps : ", swaps)


A = [random.randint(0, 1000) for x in range(8)]
print("Unsorted array", A)
mergeSort(A)
print("Sorted array", A)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it is that you have the timer calling on every single mergeSort function call. If you want the true runtime of the program, start the timer before calling mergeSort, and check the time during the function calls.